# Как использовать другой модуль чтобы избежать дублирования кода?

Tags: java, spring, intelij

Spring - Приложение состоит из нескольких модулей, которые после сборки формируются в отдельные ear - файлы
Помимо корневого, модулей два - webapp и util

Требуется из util - модуля заинжектить сервисы из webapp.

Если добавить dependency просто через intelij idea, то на время написания кода все ок, но во время компиляции - ошибка компиляции, что использованные из webapp классы - не найдены.
Как это побороть чтобы избежать дублирования кода?

Проект собирается с помощью maven, pom.xml корневого модуля(в который вложены webapp и util)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
        <artifactId>MyProject-parent</artifactId>
        <version>${MyProject.version}</version>
        <relativePath>MyProject-parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>MyProject</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven-antrun-plugin.version>1.8</maven-antrun-plugin.version>
        <maven-assembly-plugin.version>3.1.0</maven-assembly-plugin.version>
        <maven-ear-plugin.version>3.0.1</maven-ear-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>MyProject-webapp</module>
        <module>MyProject-util</module>
        <module>MyProject-parent</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-antrun-plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-assembly-plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-ear-plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>construct-build</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <ant antfile="build.xml" target="build" inheritRefs="true"/>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>ru.lanit.bpm.goblin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>goblin-ant-base-tasks</artifactId>
                        <version>${goblin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package-build</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>src/assembly/assembly-build.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

pom.xml модуля webapp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
        <artifactId>MyProject-parent</artifactId>
        <version>${MyProject.version}</version>
        <relativePath>../MyProject-parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>MyProject-webapp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>MyProject-webapp</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>4.3.13.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.batch>3.0.8.RELEASE</spring.batch>
        <javax.servlet>3.0.1</javax.servlet>
        <spring.test>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.test>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.25</slf4j.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>MyProject</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test</testSourceDirectory>
    </build>
</project>
```

pom.xml util модуля:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<parent>
    <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyProject-parent</artifactId>
    <version>${MyProject.version}</version>
    <relativePath>../MyProject-parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>MyProject-util</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>MyProject-util</name>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <finalName>MyProject-util-util</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: А как вы свой проект собираете? Используете ли maven? Если да, то приложите pom.

Comment: @Tankred Обновлено

Answer (score 1):

Не вижу в ваших pom файлах зависимостей модулей между собой:

Если нужно чтобы в util были доступны классы от webapp, то в pom.xml util-модуля вы должны добавить зависимости:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
        <artifactId>MyProject-webapp</artifactId>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Если наоборот (в webapp видеть util классы) то соответственно нужно дополнить webapp-модуль pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
        <artifactId>MyProject-util</artifactId>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Добавил как модуль зависимости в intelij idea зависимость и в pom.xml, но при сборке все равно ругает что не видит такого package

Comment: Если не использовать ни одного класса из модуля, от которого завишу - то собирается

Comment: @Roberto и не увидит, потому что все артефакты вида war, артефакт, в котором общий код, должен иметь packaging jar